# Shift control points from Bezier curves

Tags: bezier

Is it possible to add an offset to the control points of the bezier curves to make my red line to pass through the center of the point cloud?
Here is my mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz} 
    \usetikzlibrary{chains}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
    \usetikzlibrary{trees}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{8,108,131}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{adjustbox}      
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        scale=0.8,
        transform shape,
        show background rectangle,
        background rectangle/.style={fill=gray!10},
        box/.style={draw, font=\itshape}
          ]
        \coordinate (b) at (current page.center);
        \node [
            label=right:XXX, 
        ] (firewall)at(b) {\includegraphics[width=9mm]{example-image-a}};
        \node [
            label=above:XXX
        ] (client) at ([yshift=2cm]firewall){\includegraphics[width=9mm]{example-image-a}};
        \node [
            label=XXX
        ] (dnsServer)  at([xshift=-5cm]firewall){\includegraphics[width=9mm]{example-image-a}};
       \node [
            label=center:XXX,
        ] (cloud) at ([yshift=-2cm]firewall){\includegraphics[width=9mm]{example-image-b}};
        \node [
            label=below:XXX
        ] (server1) at([xshift=5cm]cloud){\includegraphics[width=9mm]{example-image-a}};
        \node [
            label=right:XXX
        ] (server2) at([xshift=5cm]server1){\includegraphics[width=9mm]{example-image-a}};
       \draw [thick,mycolor,->](client) .. controls  (firewall) .. (dnsServer)node[very near start, left]{1};
        \draw [thick,mycolor,->](dnsServer) .. controls (firewall)and (cloud) .. (server1)node[very near end, left]{2};
        \draw [thick,mycolor,<->](server1)--(server2)node[midway,above]{3 et 4};
        \draw [thick,mycolor,->](server1) .. controls  (cloud) and (firewall)..  (client)node[very near start, right]{5};
        \draw [thick,red,->](client) .. controls  (firewall) and (cloud)..  (server1)node[]{};
        \path[mycolor,->] (client) edge  [loop right] node {6} ();
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And here is the output:
[image: Output]

Comment: If [this](https://i.imgur.com/iLHgRNM.png) is what you want, then just set both the control in the red line to cloud: `.. controls (cloud) ..` in place of `.. controls (firewall) and (cloud) ..`.

Comment: Oky, this will do it, but is there any option to add an offset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that close to what you are asking for:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz} 
    \usetikzlibrary{chains}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
    \usetikzlibrary{trees}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{8,108,131}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{adjustbox}      
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        scale=0.8,
        transform shape,
        show background rectangle,
        background rectangle/.style={fill=gray!10},
        box/.style={draw, font=\itshape}
          ]
        \coordinate (b) at (current page.center);
        \node [
            label=right:XXX, 
        ] (firewall)at(b) {\includegraphics[width=9mm]{example-image-a}};
        \node [
            label=above:XXX
        ] (client) at ([yshift=2cm]firewall){\includegraphics[width=9mm]{example-image-a}};
        \node [
            label=XXX
        ] (dnsServer)  at([xshift=-5cm]firewall){\includegraphics[width=9mm]{example-image-a}};
       \node [
            %label=center:XXX,
        ] (cloud) at ([yshift=-2cm]firewall){\includegraphics[width=9mm]{example-image-b}};
        \node [
            label=below:XXX
        ] (server1) at([xshift=5cm]cloud){\includegraphics[width=9mm]{example-image-a}};
        \node [
            label=right:XXX
        ] (server2) at([xshift=5cm]server1){\includegraphics[width=9mm]{example-image-a}};
       \draw [thick,mycolor,->](client) .. controls  (firewall) .. (dnsServer)node[very near start, left]{1};
        \draw [thick,mycolor,->](dnsServer) .. controls (firewall)and (cloud) .. (server1)node[very near end, left]{2};
        \draw [thick,mycolor,<->](server1)--(server2)node[midway,above]{3 et 4};
        \draw [thick,mycolor,->](server1) .. controls  (cloud) and (firewall)..  (client)node[very near start, right]{5};
        \draw [thick,red,->](client) .. controls  ([yshift=-2.5cm]firewall) and ([xshift=-1cm]cloud)..  (server1)node[]{};
        \path[mycolor,->] (client) edge  [loop right] node {6} ();
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Warok Pleased to know that your problem is fixed

Answer (score 3):

While @Hafid Boukhoulda gives a **flexible, general** approach for offset, setting both the control points to the same point `(cloud)` makes the Beizer curve look **smooth, simple and beautiful** -- and hence could be another choice to consider if it meets your requirements.

[image]

...for which I used the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz} 
  \usetikzlibrary{chains}
  \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
  \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
  \usetikzlibrary{trees}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{8,108,131}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{adjustbox}    
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=0.8,
    transform shape,
    show background rectangle,
    background rectangle/.style={fill=gray!10},
    box/.style={draw, font=\itshape}
    ]
    \coordinate (b) at (current page.center);
    \node [label=right:XXX] 
       (firewall)at(b) {\includegraphics[width=9mm]{example-image-a}};
    \node [label=above:XXX] 
       (client) at ([yshift=2cm]firewall){\includegraphics[width=9mm]{example-image-a}};
    \node [label=XXX]
       (dnsServer)  at([xshift=-5cm]firewall){\includegraphics[width=9mm]{example-image-a}};
    \node [label=center:{}]
       (cloud) at ([yshift=-2cm]firewall){\includegraphics[width=9mm]{example-image-b}};
    \node [label=below:XXX]
       (server1) at([xshift=5cm]cloud){\includegraphics[width=9mm]{example-image-a}};
    \node [label=right:XXX]
       (server2) at([xshift=5cm]server1){\includegraphics[width=9mm]{example-image-a}};
    \draw [thick,mycolor,->](client) .. controls  (firewall) .. (dnsServer)node[very near start, left]{1};
    \draw [thick,mycolor,->](dnsServer) .. controls (firewall)and (cloud) .. (server1)node[very near end, left]{2};
    \draw [thick,mycolor,<->](server1)--(server2)node[midway,above]{3 et 4};
    \draw [thick,mycolor,->](server1) .. controls  (cloud) and (firewall)..  (client)node[very near start, right]{5};
    \draw [thick,red,->](client) .. controls (cloud) ..  (server1)node[]{};
                        % only one control (cloud) instead of two
    \path[mycolor,->] (client) edge  [loop right] node {6} ();
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```